# Is it possible to call getSupportFragmentManager in fragment that is in AppCompactActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity, fragmentmanager

How could I call getSupportFragmentManager in fragment that is in AppCompactActivity?

Comment: please post your code to give some idea where you want to call getSupportFragmentManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to import import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in my Fragment. Not a import android.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

You can access getSupportFragmentManager from fragment inside activity with

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No. It didn't help. I can't access it.

Comment: I am able to access inside my fragment with same code. when you say cant access it, you are not able to call or you are getting null ?